# Using python and metadata api to pull translated picklist values

Tags: metadata-api, translation, python, translation-workbench

We have data that will have picklist values that have been translated on salesforce using the translation workbench.

I have used simplesalesforce to connect to the rest api and that is working just fine.

What i need to be able to do is, in python, access the translated picklist values via the metadata api.

using https://github.com/sun30nil/python-SalesforceMetadataAPISupport I have been able to connect to the metadata api and make a listMetadata request.

What I need to know is I have an object and a field on that object what metadata api calls do I need to make to pull that data out?

I have looked at other similar questions but they haven't referenced the calls but what appears to be java code structured from the WSDL which is no help to me. I need to simulate calls but I'm not sure which.

Comment: There's no API to get the label for a specific language, is that what you're after? You would have to set up a separate integration user for each language.

Comment: yes I am, could I change the language of the user I have logged in via either the rest or metadata api?

Comment: There are a few fields that should control it on the `User` [object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm): `LanguageLocaleKey`and `LocaleSidKey`. I don't have any recommendations about usage in your context but you can play around with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [SalesforceMetadataModule.py](https://github.com/sun30nil/python-SalesforceMetadataAPISupport/blob/master/SalesforceMetadataModule.py) as a template I was able to add to this python metadata api code a readMetadata method:

```
def readMetadata(self, metaType, fullNames):
    """
    Read Metadata from salesforce
    :param metaType: The type of data ex. CustomObjectTranslation
    :param fullNames: the full name of the object from ListMetadata
    :return: metadata for the object requested
    """

    headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml', 'SOAPAction': 'retrieve'}
    body = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:met="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <soapenv:Header>
        <met:CallOptions>
        </met:CallOptions>
        <met:SessionHeader>
           <met:sessionId>""" + self.sessionId + """</met:sessionId>
        </met:SessionHeader>
     </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <met:readMetadata>
           <met:type>""" + metaType + """</met:type>
           <met:fullNames>""" + fullNames + """</met:fullNames>
        </met:readMetadata>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>"""

    response = requests.post(
        self.metadataServerUrl, data=body, headers=headers)
    listOfResult = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
    return listOfResult['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][u'readMetadataResponse'][u'result']
```

Which I was able to pull translations from by doing readMetadata("CustomTranslationObject", object-name)

Seeing what translations are available via listMetadata("CustomTranslationObject, "37.0") and parsing through that input.